# Handle falsy arguments

Tags: javascript

Is there any clean way to assign default values to a function, if any of its arguments are falsy.

**I know that you can do something like**

```
function addSomething(element, someArr = []) {
  someArr.push(element);
}
```

But this doesnt handle if the second argument is null and you would then get a "cannot read property 'push' of null".

**I hoped the below would have worked**

```
function addSomething(element, someArr || []) {
  someArr.push(element);
}
```

....

**So im i left doing the check inside the method?**

```
function addSomething(element, someArr) {
  someArr = someArr || [];
  someArr.push(element);
  // OR
  someArr && someArr.push(element);
}
```

**Or is there a pattern that I have missed**

Comment: No, that's pretty much it.

Comment: If your concern is when you've got more arguments, and that you want to avoid one of these in the middle, you can always call your function with `undefined` instead of null.

Comment: @Kaiido The problem is that it will be either data or null that will be passed to the function. API calls, i could check the vars before passing them to the function but i wanted the function itself to be "secure" and fail silently

Answer (score 2):

Your code is the best you can hope.
`null` is different from an array, so if you explicitly pass it into your function it should:

- Fail loudly because there is a bug in the program. You wanted an array and got a null.
- Handle it gracefully because you want to allow `null` as well.

I think you want the second case. With TypeScript annotations this function might look like:

```
function addSomething(element, someArr: any[]|null)
```

And you'd be forced to explicitly acknowledge this fact.

Comment: it looks like, that it does not work. please add a working example. if you use inside of parameters `someArr = someArr || []` then you get the error `Use before declaration`

Comment: Also considering PeterMander's answer, this does not look like "the best you can hope"

Comment: The question says nothing about TypeScript; your TypeScript in the answer just obscures the point.

Comment: OP was interested in a language feature which would allow them to skip all their code. There isn't any, hence writing code by hand is what they must use.

Comment: @NinaScholz it works in the browser console. Granted it's not good code, and a linter etc. should flag it, but it'll _work_

Comment: where do you get `any[]` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't know what type `someArr` is so I threw in the broadest type possible just for the sake of a quick writedown.

Comment: @NinaScholz, I think this is TypeScript, not ES (at least it's what is written in the answer, dunno nothing about TS)

Comment: I taged it with Javascript so typescript doesnt apply for me :(, but intressting to se how other lang does it

Comment: Typescript is just a layer of type-annotations on top of JS, otherwise it's the same language. In any case I was just trying to point out how your input can be of two distinct types and you should treat it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Even your last approach isn't 100% safe:

```js
function addSomething(element, someArr) {
  someArr && someArr.push(element);
}
addSomething('test', 'foobar');
```

You have to check if the parameter is an array:

```js
function addSomething(element, someArr) {
  Array.isArray(someArr) && someArr.push(element);
}
addSomething('test', 'foobar'); // fails silently
```

Comment: I love to fail silently.

Comment: This is true, good point. I was only concerned with null because that is what i get if the API call failed. So the arg would either always be arr of null. But if somebody tries to put a string in of course it will fail. But Array.isArray(someArr) is better since i want the function to be robust. Will mark this as the excepted answer soon, want to see other opinions as well... But basically i should do >  `someArr = Array.isArray(someArr) || [];` (i use array methods multiple times in that function)